# No matching function for call to C++ constructor

Tags: c++, class

I saw numerous similar posts, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211319/no-matching-function-for-call-to-class-constructor), but none solved my issue.

I have 2 classes, `Cache`, and `Reader`:

**Cache.hpp**

```cpp
class Cache {
public:
    explicit Cache(unsigned int max_files);

private:
    size_t max_size;
```

**Cache.cpp**

```cpp
Cache::Cache(unsigned int max_files): max_files(max_files) {}
```

**Reader.hpp**

```cpp
class Reader{
public:
    Reader(unsigned int num_files = 4);

private:
    mutable Cache my_cache;
```

**Reader.cpp**

```cpp
Reader::Reader(unsigned int num_files){
    if (num_files > 10){
        num_files = 10;
    }
    my_cache(num_files);
}
```

At compilation, I get this error:

```
In constructor ‘Reader::Reader(unsigned int)’: error: no matching function for call to ‘Cache::Cache()’
   16 | Reader::Reader(unsigned int num_files) {
        note: candidate: ‘Cache::Cache(unsigned int)’
   26 |         explicit Cache(unsigned int max_files);
```

Comment: You have got member initialization syntax wrong. It should be `Reader::Reader(unsigned int num_files) : my_cache(num_files) { }`

Comment: Change

    Reader::Reader(unsigned int num_files){
        my_cache(num_files);
    }

to

    Reader::Reader(unsigned int num_files) : my_cache(num_files){
        
    }

The reason is that you need to have Cache initialised, but you need it BEFORE the Reader class is created, because you don't have a default constructor (i.e. Cache()).

Comment: Won't that be like doing `my_cache = num_files`, instead of calling the `Cache` constructor?

Comment: @DanielCJacobs The answer you linked to in your question -- why didn't you try the accepted answer?  That would have solved your problem.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie oh, it seems I just didn't rightly understand how member initialization works; hence my previous comment

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Oh, also I left out a line that I thought wasn't relevant, where I modify `num_files` inside the `Reader` constructor before calling the `Cache` constructor.

Comment: @DanielCJacobs You might be able to use num_files > 10 ? 10 : num_files in constructor directly, and side step your problem.  (I cant remember if that kind of expression is allowed)

Comment: You still should use member initialization. For example: `Reader::Reader(unsigned int num_files) : my_cache(num_files < 10 ? num_files : 10) {}` There is simply no syntax to initialize members outside of the member initialization list.

Answer (score 1):

`my_cache(num_files);` in the constructor `Reader::Reader` is trying to invoke on `my_cache` (as a functor) with argument `num_files`; it won't perform initialization on `my_cache`. Instead, before entering the body of the constructor, `my_cache` will be default-initialized firstly, but `Cache` doesn't have a default constructor.

You should initialize `my_cache` in member initializer list as

```
Reader::Reader(unsigned int num_files) : my_cache(num_files) { // initialize my_cache by Cache::Cache(unsigned int)
}
```

**EDIT**

For the constructor,

```
Reader::Reader(unsigned int num_files){
    if (num_files > 10){
        num_files = 10;
    }
    my_cache(num_files);
}
```

It seems you want to initialize `my_cache` in the constructor body, but the [initialization order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor#Initialization_order) is fixed:

> ...
>
> 3. Then, non-static data member are initialized in order of declaration in the class definition.
> 4. Finally, the body of the constructor is executed

That means `my_cache` must be initialized before entering the constructor body.

You can make a helper function to calculate the size then use it to initialize `my_cache` in member initializer list.

Comment: This question should be closed as typo, it doesn't need an answer.

Comment: @SergeyA @songyuanyao please re-open. I updated the `Reader` constructor to show why I didn't use member initialization.

Comment: @DanielCJacobs You still can't do what you need to do the way you are doing it. The only place in a constructor that you can initialize a member is in the member initializer list. Everything else is an assignment or a mistake. You can modify `num_files` with a helper function, [`std::min`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) looks good, in the initializer list.  eg: `: my_cache(std::min(num_files,10))`

Comment: @DanielCJacobs Answer revised.